# Writing Likelihood in terms of Errors?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survival, likelihood

In the context of Survival Models (e.g. AFT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_failure_time_model), I have usually seen the Likelihood Function written as follows (https://hal-univ-pau.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02953269/document):

$$ L(\theta, \mathbf{obs}, \mathbf{\delta}) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( f(t_i \mid x_i, \theta) \right)^{\delta_i} \left( S(t_i \mid x_i, \theta) \right)^{1-\delta_i} $$

Here, the likelihood is a product of the Event Time Distribution for cases that are not censored and the Survival Function for cases that are censored.

Recently, I saw the Likelihood Function for the same model written in a different way (https://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/7210/f15/notes/10-15.pdf):

$$ Y_i = \mathbf{x}_i^\top \beta + \sigma W_i $$
$$ L(\beta, \sigma \mid y, d) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{\sigma}f(W_i)\right)^{d_i}S(W_i)^{1-d_i} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{\sigma}\lambda(W_i)\right)^{d_i}S(W_i) $$

I understand that "lambda" = "f" divided by "S" - therefore, "f(Wi)^di" can be replaced with "lambda(Wi)^di" multiplied by "S(Wi)^di". And that "S(Wi)^di" *"S(Wi)^1-di" becomes "S(Wi)" - thus, "f" can be replaced with "lambda".

**My Question:** Is there any reason that they decided to define the Likelihood Function in terms of the "Error Distribution" instead of the "Event Time Distribution"? Does this make it easier to solve?

Thanks!